# Django - User should only able to vote once

Tags: python, django, vote

i want that a user is only able to vote once for a category-request but somehow i get the following error and i dont know how to "properly" call the instance at that point:

> Cannot assign "1": "CategoryRequests_Voter.voted" must be a
>   "CategoryRequests" instance.

models.py

```
# Category Requests Model
class CategoryRequests(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    ....

# Vote(s) of Category Requests Model
class CategoryRequests_Voter(models.Model):
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voted = models.ForeignKey(CategoryRequests, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    published_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
```

views.py

```
def category_request_up_vote (request, pk):
    category_request = get_object_or_404(CategoryRequests, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if CategoryRequests_Voter.objects.filter(voter=request.user, voted=category_request.pk).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'You already voted for this request.')
        else:
            category_request.up_vote = F('up_vote') + 1
            category_request.save()
            CategoryRequests_Voter.objects.create(voter=request.user, voted=category_request.pk)
            messages.success(request, 'You have successfully Provided an Up-Vote for this Request')
            return redirect('category_request_detail', pk=category_request.pk)
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Uuups, something went wrong, please try again.')
        return redirect('category_request_detail', pk=category_request.pk)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Change `voter=request.user, voted=category_request.pk` to `voter=request.user, voted=category_request` (it makes sense to do this not only for the `.create(..)`, but for the `.exists(..)` as well.

Comment: Merci! Works fine

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix the `voted` argument to just `category_request`, not its primary key, like:

```
CategoryRequests_Voter.objects.create(voter=request.user, voted=category_request)
```

You can however improve your model and view to improve consistency, and elegance. In order to prevent a `User` from voting twice or more, you can prevent creating creating a `CategoryRequest_Voter` object twice for the *same* `voter` and `voted`, by using a `unique_together` constraint:

```
class CategoryRequests_Voter(models.Model):
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voted = models.ForeignKey(CategoryRequests, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    published_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('voter', 'voted')

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
```

Furthermore we can use a `get_or_create` and thus make only a single fetch from the database. Typically a view that changes data should do this with a POST request, not with a GET. GET requests are not supposed to have side effects.

```
def category_request_up_vote (request, pk):
    category_request = get_object_or_404(CategoryRequests, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        __, created = CategoryRequests_Voter.objects.get_or_create(
            voter=request.user,
            voted=category_request
        )
        if created:
            category_request.up_vote = F('up_vote') + 1
            category_request.save()
            messages.success(request, 'You have successfully Provided an Up-Vote for this Request')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'You already voted for this request.')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Uuups, something went wrong, please try again.')
    return redirect('category_request_detail', pk=category_request.pk)
```

It might be worth to count the number of `CategoryRequest_Voter`s, instead of incrementing the vote count, since it is possible that, for example due to deletion of `User`s, or votes, eventually the number of votes is no longer in harmony with the number of `CategoryRequests_Voter`s for that `CategoryRequests` object.

Perhaps counting the number of objects is not that efficient *per* vote, but you could make a task that runs every now and then, and thus calculate:

```
CategoryRequests_Voter.objects.filter(voted=category_request).count()
```

to count the number of `CategoryRequests_Voter` for the given `category_request`.

Comment: I tryd to implement your optimization but it seems that i alway end in the last else statement

Answer (score 0):

```
def category_request_up_vote (request, pk):
    category_request = get_object_or_404(CategoryRequests, pk=pk)
    try:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            if CategoryRequests_Voter.objects.filter(voter=request.user, voted=category_request).exists():
                messages.error(request, 'You already voted for this request.')
                return redirect('category_request_detail', pk=category_request.pk)
            else:
                category_request.up_vote = F('up_vote') + 1
                category_request.save()
                CategoryRequests_Voter.objects.create(voter=request.user, voted=category_request)
                messages.success(request, 'You have successfully Provided an Up-Vote for this Request')
                return redirect('category_request_detail', pk=category_request.pk)
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Uuups, something went wrong, please try again.')
            return redirect('category_request_detail', pk=category_request.pk)
    except:
        messages.error(request, 'Uuups, something went wrong, please try again.')
        return redirect('category_request_detail', pk=category_request.pk)
```